# Pull request decoration did not happen warning with BitBucket Server

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket, sonarqube-scan, bitbucket-server

I need to restart the Sonarqube to get rid of this warning, then it comes back after a while.

What is the reason for this? how can I get rid of this permanently?

I read the official documentation, community questions/topics and confirmed everything bitbucket server, credentailsbut everything is there but nothing helped.

The command I am using in Jenkinsfile

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sonarqube-token', variable: 'SONARQUBE_LOGIN')]) {
   sh "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=${SONARQUBE_LOGIN} -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${CHANGE_ID} -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${CHANGE_BRANCH} -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${CHANGE_TARGET}"
}
```

sonar-projects.properties

```
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.example.org
sonar.projectKey=Key_Slug
sonar.projectName=repoName
sonar.sources=test
```

SonarQube 8.4.2

[image]

Comment: Increase logging to DEBUG and inspect the logs when the decoration happens. It should tell you something more.